# Meteor.js - Fetch/Get Enrollment token (from Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail)

Tags: javascript, meteor

I can't figure out how to get the enrollment token from the  Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail function.

I know this function sends a direct mail towards the user which in the end looks something like this:

http://localhost:3000/#/enroll-account/FCXzBbqHInZgBlLaOpu8Iv11jP9DJEG-e1auAHDsh6S

However, I would need to somehow get only to the token part FCXzBbqHInZgBlLaOpu8Iv11jP9DJEG-e1auAHDsh6S as I want to send enrollment mail trough a different service (e.g Postmark)

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(userId, email)` function generates a random token and saves it in the user's `services.password.reset.token` field.

The code that generates the token is:

```
  var token = Random.secret();
  var when = new Date();
  var tokenRecord = {
    token: token,
    email: email,
    when: when
  };
  Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: {
    "services.password.reset": tokenRecord
  }});
```

(You can view the function's source code [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L595)).

It then sends an email to the user using the `Email` package. If you want to use a different service to send the email, you basically have 2 options:

- Use the same convention yourself (i.e, create the same record and use your own email service in your own function).
- Use the existing function, allow the mail delivery to fail silently and then query the user's document for the token and send the email yourself.

Neither is a particularly good option, but both will work for the time being. I wish they had refactored this part into its own function.

Note that the accounts packages are expected to undergo some changes towards the release of the next Meteor versions.

BTW, this function is very similar to `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail`, which you may also wish to override or create your own version.

Comment: Oh man thanks a bunch for clarifying this to me! Have spent the whole weekend trying to get my head around this!

Comment: Glad to have helped. There is nothing like looking at the source code and tests to get a better understanding of the internals.